# android - array list update in two users online

Tags: java, android, firebase, arraylist

i need to provide me the way to do this:

for example i have application that the content recyclerview there is button to add items into recyclerview ,
note : this above part i knew how do it:
but :

when i add item in recyclerview immediately it will add in my friend online 
 as well when will be delete it will delete from my freind in real time .

also it will send in specific user in app so app content users in online host

but the problem is how to send in realtime to specific user and do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way is to use firebase realtime database
You will need to use the value event listener which you will set to listen to specific node and when any change happen in the value of this need the listener will fire at the same time so if you add item to this node

Recycler View App:

```
DatabaseReference usersRef = ref.child("users");
Map<String, User> users = new HashMap<String, User>();
users.put("New user", new User("Alan Turing"));
usersRef.setValue(users);
```

Friend App :

```
DatabaseReference usersRef = ref.child("users");
userRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override public void onDataChange (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
        // code here does not get executed straight away,
        // it gets executed whenever data is received back from the remote database
    }


});
```